# What´s the best strategy to private docker QA and PROD env

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-registry

If i have the QA env and have the PRD env.

Should i have only one docker registry to push the images ?

I mean,
If i have the version 1.0.0

And i will have a 1.1.0

Do i generate the 1.1.0 as the latest using only one registry ? And so fix the image version in prod ? So i will need to manually update the PRD compose file to update..

Or maybe its better i have two registry.. and can i make the QA autodeploy using latest.. and so when that has passed, i can push the same image with latest to PRD registry..

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to have a single repo and tag (version) your images (just like you do on the code repo). For example you could do `image-name:1.0.0`

Another option is use the same tagging strategy, but add a prefix on the tag, like `image-name:qa-1.0.0`, that way you can be 100% sure you're using the correct env image.

But as I said, the best practice is use a single image for all environments and just use variables to change whatever needed, that way you keep consistency between environments.

Comment: Hi Diego, but still my question.
1 - using image names i think is not a option, because i have only one image
2 - with a single image, the question is.. if i use a fixed version image-name:1.0.0 and dont use the aditional tag 'latest', how i can auto deploy new versions of my services ?

Comment: For that you need a CD (continous delivery) flow. based on your question I see you use docker-compose which is not the best. what you should use is some kind of container management tool like kubernetes, ECS, nomad, etc. that way you can talk to the APIs once the image is up and tell to use the new version image-name:1.0.1 for example